# Extract portions of a HTML table with Python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I want to extract portions of a HTML page using Python.

For instance: take this page

http://www.wsdot.com/traffic/traveltimes/default.aspx?region=seattle&direction=all

Let's say I want to extract Distance, Current Travel Time and HOV Time for the route Bellevue-Bothell.

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: You'll need an HTML parser. [`beautifulsoup4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup performs html escape which I believe is what you want. I've used some time ago and it worked just fine.

Take a look at the documentation [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)